# hiding and showing div elements doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `side menu` which has two `buttons`. By default, I would like to see the content of the `profile` `div` (which works now), but when clicking on the `My reviews` button on the `sidebar`, I would like to hide the content of the  `profile` `div` and instead show the `review`  `div`. But it doesn't work.

I have the following code:

```
<nav class="side-menu">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
        <li class="active">
         <button id="profilebtn" type="submit">
         <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
         </button>
        </li>
        <li >               
         <form action="/findUserReviews" method="POST">
         <button id="reviewbtn" type="submit" class="">
         <a href="#review"></a>My Review</button>
         </form>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>

<div id="review" >
  <table>
   <tbody>
        <tr th:each="review: ${reviews}">
          <form th:action="@{/edit_review}" method="post">
          <td class="underline font-weight-bold"
            th:text="${review.place.id}" />
          <td>
            <button type="submit" class="edit" name="action"
            value="edit">Edit</button>
          </td>
         </form>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="profile" >
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/edit_profile}">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <h3 class="fieldset-title">Personal Info</h3>
            ...
        </fieldset>                             
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is my `jquery` code:

```
    <script >
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#reviewbtn").click(function() {
                   $("#profile").hide();
                   $("#review").show(); 
                 });
                })
    </script>
```

What I get is the `profile` div by default which is expected, but when I click on `My review` button, I see the result of this div on top of what I can see for `profile` div. When I click on the `profile` button, I see again just the result for the  `profile` `div` element, but it jumps to a bit upper.
I actually want to see the results at the same place of the page, just the content must be changed based on the clicked button.

Any help is appreciated.

DEMO:

```js
$("#reviewbtn").click(function() {
  $("#profile").hide();
  $("#review").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="reviewbtn" type="submit" class=""><a href="#review"></a>My Review</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id="review" style="display:none">
  This is a review div
</div>
<div id="profile">
  This is a profile div
</div>
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain what exactly this question has to do with Java? Sorry, I do not understand

Comment: Not getting what you mean. Could you please try to explain it using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @palaѕн Thanks a lot for your comment. When I click on "my reviews" I would like to hide the profile div and just show the review div. But it doesn't work. I see both divs.

Comment: I am not sure how can that happen, as you are using that logic only inside `$("#reviewbtn").click`. Can you create a small demo for this with only click event and divs and try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @palaѕн What's wrong with the logic? When clicking on "reviewbtn" I would like to hide the profile div. I'm really naive in jquery. Sorry.

Comment: I never said anything is wrong in the code. I am just saying please share a demo with minima code where just click event and divs and nothing else, where you can show profile div is not hiding and review div is not showing on click. I have added a small demo for you. Please update it to show the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I used CSS display and it works. Note: I changed reviewbtn type into button, because  it was submit type and it was trying to submit something. If you need it just to run JS, it can not bee submit button.

Also changed profile button so You can go back and forward for demonstration purpose.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#reviewbtn").click(function() {
                   $("#profile").css("display", "none");
                   $("#review").css("display", "block"); 
                 });
                 
                 $("#profilebtn").click(function() {
                   $("#profile").css("display", "block");
                   $("#review").css("display", "none"); 
                 });
                 
                  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="side-menu">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
        <li class="active">
         <button id="profilebtn" type="button">
         <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
         </button>
        </li>
        <li >               
         <form action="/findUserReviews" method="POST">
         <button id="reviewbtn" type="button" class="">
         <a href="#review"></a>My Review</button>
         </form>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>

<div id="review" style="display:none">
  <table>
   <tbody>
        <tr th:each="review: ${reviews}">
          <form th:action="@{/edit_review}" method="post">
          <td class="underline font-weight-bold"
            th:text="${review.place.id}" />
          <td>
            <button type="submit" class="edit" name="action"
            value="edit">Edit</button>
          </td>
         </form>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="profile" style="display:block">
    <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/edit_profile}">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <h3 class="fieldset-title">Personal Info</h3>
            ...
        </fieldset>                             
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and writing the code. But unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. When I click on profile, I can see the correct div and that's fine, but clicking on my review doesn't do anything and the page is completely clear. I think one reason is that the review button should be of type form, as I am submitting a form to the spring controller. Anyway, even changing it to submit doesn't solve the problem. When it is a submit button, I see the result of the review div for a second and then it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

So in other cases you would have to make both divs `position: absolute` and the parent element to `position: relative`. This way both divs stack on top of each other. But since you are using `hide()` which sets `display: none` they don't use any space.

If change the content of a div, I would recomend you to put both in a div.

I am not exactly sure if this code snippet is what you want, tell me if you need more.

```js
$("#reviewbtn").click(function() {
  $("#profile").hide();
  $("#review").show();
});

$("#profilebtn").click(function() {
  $("#review").hide();
  $("#profile").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="profilebtn" type="submit" class=""><a href="#review"></a>Profile</button>
<button id="reviewbtn" type="submit" class=""><a href="#review"></a>My Review</button>

<div id="SomeWrapper">
    <div id="review" style="display: none; background: red;">
        This is a review div
    </div>
    <div id="profile" style="display: block; background: blue;">
        This is a profile div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code but it doesn't work unfortunately. It seems that using spring boot and collecting data from a model is to somehow problematic. With your code, when I click on the my review buttion, I just see the results for a second and then it's gone. I know that many people here are real experts, but I have the same problem with the other answers which were suggested here, as well.

Comment: If I remove the thi form:`<form action="/findUserReviews" method="POST">` and use the two click listener that I die above, it works.

Comment: but I don't want to remove it. Upon clicking on the button, I exactly aim at submitting this form, collecting the information from the controller and then showing the results on a div. Without that, the code is nonesense.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) jQuery method to switch between show/hide elements:

```js
$("#reviewbtn").click(function() {
  $("#profile").toggle();
  $("#review").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="reviewbtn" type="submit" class=""><a href="#review"></a>My Review</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id="review" style="display:none">
  This is a review div
</div>
<div id="profile">
  This is a profile div
</div>
```